# Knights and Knaves - Three People

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Knights and Knaves Problem: There are three people A, B, and C. One of them is a cop. They say the following:
>
> A: I am not a cop
>
> B: The cop is a knave
>
> C: All three of us are knaves
>
> Is the cop a knight or a knave?

My answer: the cop is a knave because that person is person A. If Person C is a knight, and everyone is a knave, then person A is lying. I am not sure if my reasoning or answer is correct and would really like some help please. Thank you.

Comment: Person $C$ can not be a knight (because then $C's$ claim would be a lie).  Thus we know that $C$ is a knave but that at least one of the other two must be a knight.

Comment: Hint;  I do not believe there is enough information to determine which person is the cop.  However, you were not asked to determine that.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but $A$ is not necessarily a cop...

Comment: Many of us know the "knights and knaves" setup, but if you are asking questions, you should make them self-contained and say what knights and knaves are. Who knows some interested youngster might be scanning the questions for something interesting, and this is certainly an interesting logic question of that kind. (Knights only ever make true statements, Knaves always make false statements)

Comment: Note that to answer the question you need to determine the truth value of Bs statement. You could attack it directly and see whether B=T or B=F gives you a contradiction. Even if not immediate, it will throw light on where you need to focus to solve it.

Comment: Would that mean C is a knave, B is a knave if assuming B=T. And that A is a knight. Therefore B is the cop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ cannot be a knight - he would be calling himself a knave.

1. (from $C$): $C$ is a knave, and either $A$ or $B$ (or both) is a knight.
2. (from $B$): $B$ is not a cop.
3. (from $A$): $A$ is either a knave cop, or he is a knight non-cop meaning $C$ is a knave cop.

Which also incidentally shows that $B$ is a knight.